# Cannot Install ECF SDK due to missing bundle?

Tags: eclipse, discovery, eclipse-ecf

I wanted to use DocShare for eclipse so I downloaded the zip file for installing the ECF SDK from the eclipse site and went to install new software in eclipse gave it the path of the zip file and deselected the "Contact all sites during....required software" checkbox beacuse it took too long.
The result was an error stating:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ECF SDK for Eclipse 3.9.0.v20140818-1747 (org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.group 3.9.0.v20140818-1747)
  Missing requirement: ECF Discovery UI 3.0.0.v20140818-1747 (org.eclipse.ecf.discovery.ui 3.0.0.v20140818-1747) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui [2.2.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ECF SDK for Eclipse 3.9.0.v20140818-1747 (org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.group 3.9.0.v20140818-1747)
    To: org.eclipse.ecf.discovery.ui [3.0.0.v20140818-1747]
```

I have no idea what this means and couldn't find any solutions for it. Can someone please help me? Thanks

The site from where I downloaded the zip file: http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/downloads.php

Comment: Try using the 'Install via p2 repository' method described on the ECF downloads page.

Comment: @greg-449, do i still keep the checkbox unchecked?

Comment: You can try without and if it fails try again with the checkbox checked.

Comment: @greg-449, keeping it unchecked results in the same error. Trying with it checked.

Comment: I checked that box but it was stuck "Calculation requirements" for abt 4 hrs

Comment: @greg-449 I got fed up and installed Eclipse Luna and removed my Kepler. The install worked like a charm. 5 minutes and it was done